# Dynamic resources for_each output in terraform module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

**Terraform v1.0.0**
**Provider: aws v3.49.0**

I created dynamic AWS subnets resources with a for_each from a module.

The resources creation is working fine, however being able to output dynamically created resources is not working and cannot find proper documentation for it.

The subnet module is

```html
resource "aws_subnet" "generic" {
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
  cidr_block = var.cidr_block
  map_public_ip_on_launch = var.public_ip_on_launch
  tags = {
        Name = var.subnet_tag_name
        Environment = var.subnet_environment
      }
}
```

With simple module output defined

```js
output "subnet_id" {
    value = aws_subnet.generic.id
}
```

Then from root module, I am creating a for_each loop over a list variable to create multiple dynamic resources from the module

```html
module "subnets" {
  source = "../modules/networking/subnet"
  for_each = var.subnets
  vpc_id = "vpc-09d6d4c17544f3a49"
  cidr_block = each.value["cidr_block"]
  public_ip_on_launch = var.public_ip_on_launch
  subnet_environment = var.subnet_environment
  subnet_tag_name = each.value["subnet_tag_name"]
}
```

When I run this without defining outputs in the root module, things get created normally. The problem comes when I try to define the outputs

```html
output "subnets" {
    value = module.subnets.*.id
    description = "Imported VPC ID"
}
```

It comes up with this error

```html
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on output.tf line 2, in output "subnets":
│    2:     value = module.subnets.*.id
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "id".
```

I tried different output definitions. Would appreciate guidance on how to properly define outputs of instances dynamically created with a for_each module.

Comment: `[*]` and `.*` can be only used with lists. This resource uses `for_each` so it outputs a `map` rather than a `list`. I would like to see how your variables file looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html#splat-expressions-with-maps), the "splat" operator (`*`) can only be used with lists, and since you're using `for_each` your output will be a map.

You need to use map/list comprehension to achieve what you want.

For an output that is a map of key/value pairs (note that I've changed the output description to something that makes more sense):

```
output "subnets" {
    value = {
        for k, v in module.subnets:
        k => v.subnet_id
    }
    description = "Subnet IDs"
}
```

For a list that only contains the subnet IDs:

```
output "subnets" {
    value = [
        for k, v in module.subnets:
        v.subnet_id
    ]
    description = "Subnet IDs"
}
```

Comment: It threw an error "This object does not have an attribute named "id".". 

Fixed that by modifying to "k => v.subnet_id" instead of id; The output of the child module. 

Thanks a lot!